# Bootstrap image not displaying on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have an image that gets displayed properly on desktop view, but becomes 0x0 when browsing from mobile. I can't seem to crack the cause of this one. The site is running Bootstrap 4 and the issue can be seen here: https://clonegram.ritvars.lv/profile/demouser

**Mobile view**
[image: Mobile view]

**Desktop view**
[image: Desktop view]

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 p-5">
        <img src="{{ $user->profile->profileImage() }}" class="rounded-circle w-100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 pt-5">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <h1 class="mr-4">{{ $user->username }}</h1>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of `padding: 3rem !important`.

You can improve it by having, some `min-height` or `min-width` and setting your padding just for larger viewport screens.